# "Element not found" exception in Jenkins box while script passing in local

Tags: watir, pageobjects, page-object-gem

Im trying to read the text from a popup and assert it.The element is defined as

```
div(:cta_description, :class => 'homepage-clicktoactiavte-description')
```

And the method as

```
  def rewards_popup_description
    return cta_description_element.when_present.text.gsub(/[^$,.A-Za-z0-9]/," ")
  end
```

This script passes successfully while running in local, but fails with the following exception while running directly on Jenkins box which is another windows machine.

```
And the customer sees the overlay popup message "$10 reward activated"
features/step_definitions/Loyalty_steps.rb:7
timed out after 30 seconds, Element not present in 30 seconds (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.12.0/lib/watir/wait.rb:49:in `until'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/watir-6.12.0/lib/watir/wait.rb:126:in `wait_until'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object/elements/element.rb:133:in `when_present'
D:/Jenkins/workspace/cog-checkout-loyalty-nightly-cuke-tests/cuke-tests/features/support/pages/Frontend/Cotton_On/Loyalty_Page.rb:14:in `rewards_popup_description'
D:/Jenkins/workspace/cog-checkout-loyalty-nightly-cuke-tests/cuke-tests/features/step_definitions/Loyalty_steps.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in '
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object/page_factory.rb:75:in `on_page'
D:/Jenkins/workspace/cog-checkout-loyalty-nightly-cuke-tests/cuke-tests/features/step_definitions/Loyalty_steps.rb:8:in `block in '
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `'
features/Loyalty-AU.feature:122:in `And the customer sees the overlay popup message "$10 reward activated"'
```

Both the machines have same version of following packages

```
page-object (2.2.4)
watir (6.12.0)
watir-scroll (0.2.0)
watir-webdriver (0.9.9)
```

Both the machines use same version of chromedriver as well

```
$ chromedriver.exe -v
ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application>chromedriver.exe -v
ChromeDriver 2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e)
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

**Note:-**
I ran the script directly from Jenkins box. Its a Windows Server 2016 edition.When the script runs I can see the popup appears and its stays for 10seconds(configured time) and then disappears. Then it fails complaining "Element no found".

The local is Windows 7 machine..

Comment: Please remove watir webdriver from your gems, it is deprecated. All the code is now in watir gem

Comment: Please add WATIR tag

Comment: Hi thanks for adding WATIR tag, people will be checking WATIR tag not page object tag so they would be missing your question. So in future please add WATIR tag.

Comment: @titusfortner, removed the watir webdriver from gemfile